# EF Code First - Duplicate Table With The Same Schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

EF 6 Code First: How is it possible to have duplicate table of the same schema.
Like History table that serves as a replica for the original table. For example:

[image]

Several Important Notes to Consider:

1. **No foreign key**: I know it can be done by inheritance and some other such methods which generate foreign key to the original table. But I mean completely different duplicated table.
2. **No Copy Past the Entity**: Coping from the `Employee` entity to `Employee_History` entity is an option but in case the original entity is big, complected and has lots of inheritances, it might be really mess. Not to mention that every change to the original table should be reflected to the history table manually by copy.
3. **DataAnnotation** is preferable.

Comment: what is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: if you are doing this as a history table then i would override the .Save or .SaveAsync methods to write in both tables on save just alter the logic for the history table that on edit enters a new row not edit existing. That would require the id of history table to compound of original id and version here is an example https://www.meziantou.net/2017/07/03/entity-framework-core-generate-tracking-columns

Comment: This is a rather broad question. Any specific problem you're facing?

Comment: @Simonare The company operates some logic and statistics on the history data. They don't want to involve both active records and deleted, history, records in one table (I presume they want the active table to be more clean then involving deleted records with deleted flag).

Comment: @markorial This is pretty nice pattern. But the question is how do I create two identical tables of one entity by EF code first. All the records will be saved in the Employee table by default. On deletion, I will create a record on the Employee_History table and delete the original record from the Employee table. So I need to create two table with the same schema and columns by EF code first.

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, how do I create two identical tables (same schema, same columns) by one entity (C# class) by EF code first? The records inside these tables shouldn't be the same in both of the tables, I'll take care of it programmatically. Actually there is an option to do so by creating a separate entity class (Employee_History) with all the properties in the Employee class. That will work fine, but please see section 2, I specified why I can not use this pattern.

Comment: i would consider using interfaces to create classes for ef to work with since i believe that creating 2 tables on the same database from the same class is not smart (or even possible) because ef will not know what to load from where in that situation or worse yet load jumble data. Maybe it would be best to create an interface inherit it and you have 2 identical classes to work with. And since you use interfaces when you change the base class all will inherit the changes.